# How can I download a large file from SageMaker Studio Lab

Tags: python, download, yolo, large-files

I have created a YOLO weight file (300MB) using Sage Maker Studio Lab, and I want to download it to my local PC.
I am able to download small files, but the "download" button does not work for large files like the YOLO weight.
How can I download a large file from SageMaker Studio Lab.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to download large files on Sagemaker I'm aware of is to zip them and download the pieces. Inconvenient, but works.

```
zip {name}.zip {full path to file to be zipped} -s 200m
```

You can get the path by right-clicking on the file and copying it, just be careful to adjust it to whatever dir you're on if running the command from the terminal.

The download limit is currently around 200mb, hence the max size parameter of 200m.

Answer (score 0):

A very good method by @Rhaenys, another alternative would be as follows.

You can use S3 bucket to help you with this task as well. Upload to a desired S3 bucket and then download it from there. Commands that will help you is `aws s3 cp [argument1] [argument2]`

In your studio, upload to the bucket using something like this (replace the BUCKET_NAME with the actual bucket name)

```
aws s3 cp model.zip s3://BUCKET_NAME/model.zip
```

and on your local you run,

```
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/model.zip ./
```